# Angular & RxJS: how to initialize a AuthGuard?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular6

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.google.com) which led me to [this stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-layout) to provide a client side authentication using angular auth guard.

In particular I have a `private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);` variable which I can use throughout my application to know whether the user is logged in or not.

However in the code above, the test made is trivial (is the user and password not empty), and I'd like to do a server authentication, but I'm facing a issue: how can I make it so that the canActivate method from the AuthGuard waits the async value returned by http.post() ? I saw that canActivate can return an Observable, but I couldn't make it work with the loggedIn variable.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, & give it a go. If you get stuck & can't get unstuck after doing more research & searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt & say specifically where you're stuck. Peeps will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. The canActivate method's return value can be an `Observable<boolean>`, `Promise<boolean>` or `boolean`. Your loggedIn property is none of those. You should instead have the canActivate call a service which in turn will be making the http request to your backend, and that will return an Observable, which you can then map the response to a boolean value.

Comment: But in that case, how do I initiliaze the loggedIn property ? I must have a way to identify in other views if I'm logged in or not easily. Could you please tell me the modifications that have to be applied to my code to make it work ? I am using the following API to mock the server:

   `curl -X POST https://reqres.in/api/login -d '{"email": "peter@klaven", "password": "cityslicka"}' -H 'content-type: application/json'`

Comment: The auth guard tells the if you're logged in or not. If you're not, then you can't even navigate to that route.

Comment: But then how do I refactor the code in stackblitz to not use this variable anymore? It is used with `|async`.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I was referencing [this similar stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-ngif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html). I got it to work with this code,

    `return this.http.post('/isAuthenticated').pipe(
       map(() => {
    this.loggedIn.next(true);
    return true;
   }),
   catchError((err) => {
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return  Observable.of(false);
   }));` Does that match what you were talking about, do you agree with this code?

Comment: Yeah I guess it works, but I don't see the point. Like I said, the AuthGuard already validates whether you're allowed to navigate to a route or not. loggedIn will always be true because you can't get to the route if it's false. That's why I find it unnecessary and it only makes your code more difficult to follow. In a real world app, you wouldn't have such a property, instead you'd manage the actual user profile which would be an object or null.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Could you please make the modifications you're talking about in [this project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-ngif) ?